# boton de accion en una notificacion en android studio kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, notificaciones

Hola amigos quiero que mi notificacion tenga un boton Actualizar que cuando lo oprima este ejecute un metodo y actualice el contenido de la notificacion, sale el boton pero cuando le doy no ejecuta nada, este es mi codigo, pero no entiendo como hacer que funcione

```
    val snoozeIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        action = "" //<- aqui es donde no se que poner para que me ejecute el metodo
        putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, 0)            
    }
    val snoozePendingIntent: PendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, snoozeIntent, 0)

    var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notificacion)            
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_SECRET)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
        .setStyle(
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(TEXT)
        )
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_notificacion, "Actualizar",
            snoozePendingIntent)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya resolvi con este codigo

```
val snoozeIntent = Intent(cont, NotificationReceiver::class.java).apply {            
        putExtra(Notification.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, 0) 
    }
    val snoozePendingIntent: PendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cont, 0, snoozeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)


    var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(cont, "default")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notificacion)            
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_SECRET)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setColor(cont.resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
        .setStyle(
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(TEXT)
        )
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_notificacion, "Actualizar",
            snoozePendingIntent)            
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
```

y la clase

```
class NotificationReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
private lateinit var dato:Datos
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    
    if (intent!=null){           

        dato = context?.let { Datos(context) }!!

        dato.actualizarnotificacion()
    }
}
```

}